# Can use functional operations

Tags: java, function, netbeans, foreach

I'm using the for-each construct in Java as follows:

```
public int getNumRStations() {
    int numRoutes = 0;

    for (ArrayList<Route> route : routes) {
        numRoutes += route.size();
    }

    return numRoutes;
}
```

NetBeans shows a warning/notice that says "Can use functional operations". Upon automatically resolving it, the newly generated code shows this:

```
public int getNumRStations() {
    int numRoutes = 0;

    numRoutes = routes.stream().map((route) -> route.size()).reduce(numRoutes, Integer::sum);

    return numRoutes;
}
```

1. Why is NetBeans warning me of this? I know I'm not supposed to blindly trust IDEs, so that's why I'm asking.
2. What is that new line supposed to do? I haven't seen anything like it, in real life or in class.

Comment: That is new Java 8 API and lambda expression.

Comment: are you already updated to java 8?

Comment: Your IDE is pretty god damn smart.

Comment: Is that actually an improvement? Seems harder to read, longer to type, and doesn't run faster.

Comment: The warning is only to do with code style, and in this case it seems you don't want it. You can probably disable it somewhere.

Comment: @immibis It's not that I don't want it, I'm trying to learn what it is and whether it is appropriate to use the new style (efficiency, maintainability concerns, etc).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That looks like  NetBeans suggesting refactoring your sum operation as a Java 8  "lambda" or functional programming operation using the map and reduce functions from the Stream interface. You must be using a Java 8 JDK with NetBeans.

Breaking down what it's doing:

- the "map()"  function is performing a count of all of your `route` sizes in your `routes` array list,
- the "reduce()" function is then performing a sum of those individual sizes to get the final result for the total number of routes.

The map() and reduce() functions are documented in the Java 8 documentation for the Stream interface available [at this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

This answer addresses "what it is" but doesn't address "why it's better". I will admit to still learning about these constructs myself.

Answer (score 8):

So @paisanco already explained about what each function does.

I agree that the modification the IDE suggested is more complex than the original.
If I were asked to select between the original one and the IDE's recommendation, then I will choose the original one.

However, here is a simpler (and more preferred) way for your example.

```
public int getNumRStations() {
    return routes.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.size()).sum();
}
```

Explanation is simpler in this case, too.
For each routes' element `x`, change it into `x.size()` and sum them up.

`x -> x.size()` is called a lambda expression, or anonymous function.
It's like

```
int function(x) {
    return x.size();
}
```

(I omitted the parameter type. The type is implicitly selected by the Java compiler.)
This function is applied to each of the collection's element. This is what `mapToInt(lambda exp)` method does.

`sum()` method doesn't seem to need explanation.

Simple, isn't it?